# What is the difference between using `[data2]` and `[[data2]]` with `groupby`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am working through a Python for data analysis tutorial and want some clarification on the output I get from using `[data2]` and `[[data2]]` when using `groupby`.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If use:

```
[data2]
```

you get `Series` with `Multiindex`.

If use subset

```
[[data2]]
```

you get `DataFrame` with `Multiindex`.

And if use:

```
df.groupby(['key1','key2'], as_index=False)['data2'].mean()
```

you get `DataFrame` with `3` columns without `Multiindex`.

Maybe it is more clear if use another form:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1':[1,2,2,1,2,2],
                   'key2':[4,4,4,4,5,5],
                   'data2':[7,8,9,1,3,5],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,9,5]})

print (df)
   D  data2  key1  key2
0  1      7     1     4
1  3      8     2     4
2  5      9     2     4
3  7      1     1     4
4  9      3     2     5
5  5      5     2     5


print (df['data2'].groupby([df.key1,df.key2]).mean())
key1  key2
1     4       4.0
2     4       8.5
      5       4.0
Name: data2, dtype: float64

print (df[['data2']].groupby([df.key1,df.key2]).mean())
           data2
key1 key2       
1    4       4.0
2    4       8.5
     5       4.0
```